# Vb6 Performing an operation based on each line of a text file

Tags: algorithm, vb6, scripting

I have a text file with a series of commands each one is on a diferent line what I need to do is go through the text file line by line and for each line perform a set of operations.  How would I loop through line by line?

Example:

Text file contains:
johndoe.log
Apples and organes.log
monkies and zebras.log

script would grab line 1(johndoe.log)
create a new text file named johndoe.log
go to line two
create a new text file named apples and organes.log
etc... until the text file is complete

I know how to do everything except the loop that performs an operation on each line of the text file :(

and I know its oranges, typoed and went with it.

Comment: Kinda sounds like it.  But I'd fire a teacher that was instructing in VB6 at this late date.

Answer (score 2):

In classic VB6:

```
Dim LineData as String
Dim FileHandle as Integer

FileHandle = FreeFile
Open "C:\Test.txt" For Input As #FileHandle
Do While Not EOF(FileHandle)
    Line Input #FileHandle, LineData
    ' Do whatever with LineData
Loop
Close #FileHandle
```

Or you can look at the `FileSystemObject`

Comment: I'm suddenly reliving my nightmares of eight years ago ... I'd managed to forget about the file handle syntax ... (Or maybe block it out?) FileSystemObject was SUCH an improvement!